# PCB Build-Up and Stack-Up alternative for 8-layer PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, high-speed, routing, stack-up

I am looking at an open-source design for an NVIDIA Jetson Nano carrier board made by a company called AntMicro. [See here](https://github.com/antmicro/jetson-nano-baseboard)
The design is an 8-layer design with the following Stack-Up and Build-Up recommendation:

[image]

And the Stack-Up:

- L1: Signal (Top Layer)
- L2: 5V Power Plane
- L3: Signal
- L4: Signal
- L5: GND Plane
- L6: 3V3 + Signal
- L7: GND Plane
- L8: Signal (Bottom Layer)

The only problem with using this design for my custom carrier board are the capabilities of my manufacturer, which in my case, is JLCPCB.

[image]

In the case of the open-source carrier board, inner copper layers are 0.035mm (~1oz) and the outer copper layers are 0.018mm (~0.5oz).

What alternative PCB Build-Up can I use to be able to manufacture the board. Ideally, I do not want to change too much of the routing and layout to be on the safest side.

Comment: You're probably better off asking on the projects GitHub page. Given this is a high-speed design with a lot of high speed (multi-gigabit) interface, there is a lot more to consider than just the copper thickness. The dielectric and prepreg (pp) material types used, core/pp thicknesses etc. All of these parameters make a difference to the board routing (impedance matching, trace widths, etc).

Comment: Looking at the JLCPCB page, I don't think they can do that dielectric stack up, so probably you need to make changes to the board or else find a different manufacturer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 18μm outer thickness is almost certainly the thickness of the un-plated copper foil (not the "*Finished thickness*" you've shown in the screenshot of JLCPCB's capabilities)... it'll likely be plated up to approx 1oz / 0.035μm (but this isn't actually specified anywhere in the project), and then plated again with a very thin layer of gold (ENIG, as mentioned in the board layout, just below the table you quoted).

Just below the table is also mention of the suggested material - "ISOLA PR2116", which is likely what the project has used to verify the design - so, I'd suggest you either accept their "Advanced PCB" service (6+ layers, but with incorrect layer heights), or look for an alternate supplier.

As always, impedance controlled traces will need to be reviewed if you want confidence that things will work on a new material and stackup.

Comment: JLC do actual do a 2116 stackup. You have to select "Impedance Control" to "Yes" and then it gives a list of their standard stackups, but ultimately the thicknesses of each core/prepreg are not exactly the same, so your point still stands (choose a more specialist supplier who can do custom or change the design to suit).

Comment: @TomCarpenter - so they do! I missed that earlier, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the board actually has 18 um finished thickness on outer layers. This simply not manufacturable at most fabs because you start with at least 9 um copper foil and plating the vias adds at least 18 um to the outer layers.

It's more likely they're specifying the copper foil thickness and not accounting for plating. The 1 oz finished thickness specified by JLPCB is going to be essentially the same.

That said, if this is a high speed design you should probably do your own impedance calculations too be sure the trace geometry will work with  35 um finished copper.